# Setting TCP_NODELAY without knowing file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

I can set TCP_NODELAY while accept the new connection like the following :

```
fd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &slen);
if (fd < 0) {
    perror("accept");
    return;
}
if (fd > FD_SETSIZE) {
    perror("fd > FD_SETSIZE\n");
    return;
}
int onex = 1 ;
setsockopt(fd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,&onex,sizeof(onex));
```

and also can set TCP_NODELAY after connect to server :

```
bzero(&addr,sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port_to_order);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr);
if(connect(iConnCenter,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0){
    printf(" to DBServer.exe socket to iConn error:== [%d]\n",port_to_order );
    return -1 ;
}
int onex = 1 ;
setsockopt(iConnCenter,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,&onex,sizeof(onex));
```

I have a case that I can not have the fd  of the connection ,
it is a library function call which have no fd information , the following is the sample :

```
TraderApi* pTrader = TraderApi::CreateTraderApi();
TraderSpi spi(pTrader) ;
pTrader->Init(g_frontaddr,&spi);
```

then use pTrader->ReqService(structA)  to do send data , in this case ,
I won't have the chance to have the connection fd , so I can not 
set TCP_NODELAY  .

I like to know in this case , how can I set TCP_NODELAY ?! Is there a config file or else I can set TCP_NODELAY for all connections happened in this application or in this Operation System ?!

The application is in box running RedHat 3.10.x86_64 .

Edit :

I have googled and found the source sample of list-open-fd.c at

https://github.com/ONsec-Lab/scripts/blob/master/list-open-fd.c

```
for( fd=0; fd<65535; fd++) {
   if( fstat( fd, &st) == -1) {
     continue;
   }

  switch (st.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
    case S_IFBLK:  printf("fd %d is block device\n", fd);            break;
    case S_IFCHR:  printf("fd %d is character device\n", fd);        break;
    case S_IFDIR:  printf("fd %d is directory\n", fd);               break;
    case S_IFIFO:  printf("fd %d is FIFO/pipe\n", fd);               break;
    case S_IFLNK:  printf("fd %d is symlink\n", fd);                 break;
    case S_IFREG:  printf("fd %d is regular file\n", fd);            break;
    case S_IFSOCK: printf("fd %d is socket\n", fd);                  break;
    default:       printf("fd %d is unknown?\n", fd);                break;
  }
} //for
```

I think I can get the fd which pTrader->Init create by checking fd with mode = IFSOCK  .

Comment: This looks like `C++`, why is it tagged `c`? Also, there may be a function like `fileno()` to get the underlying file descriptor from the stream.

Comment: File a bug report on TraderApi and have them do it.

Comment: @EOF , thanks , fileno with parameter FILE* stream , I can not fill in pTraderApi  , what parameter should I use in my case ?!

Comment: What is the outer problem here? Why do you think you want to set TCP_NODELAY?

Comment: @EJP ,  to disable  Nagle's algorithm in my application ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TraderAPI` is calling Linux socket API's, then you can intercept the calls with your own implementation that will set `TCP_NODELAY` after the socket is created by the underlying API. You would likely need to provide your intercepted calls via a shared library, and load it via `LD_PRELOAD`.

To call the real socket API, you could use `dlopen` on `libc.so` and `dlsym` the socket APIs you are intercepting and store the function pointers. Then invoke them when you need to call the real API.

Comment: thanks , I will take a look of dlopen .  I wonder if there is a function which can return all  fd this application current have , if such kind of function exist , then it is much easier to solve my problem.  also , Is there a config parameter exist in RedHat 7.1 so that default all new connections have TCP_NODELAY flag .

Comment: You can attempt to browse the current processes `/proc` entry to see the open file descriptors and attempt to detect the newly created socket, but I don't think that solution is as robust.

Comment: thanks , I have googled a list-open-fd.c , hope it can work ,